# I don't understand this derivation

Tags: derivatives

I try to unterstand a derivation and need help.

There are given two functions
$$
s=-cos(j\pi/n),s\in[-1,1]
$$
and the nonlinear transformation
$$
y(s)=C\tan[\frac{\pi(s+1)}{4}+\frac{s-1}{2}\arctan\frac{y^*}{C}]+y^*,y\in[0,\infty)
$$
$y*$ and $C$ are constant parameters.

The derivation and its solution is
$$
\frac{ds}{dy(s)}=4C/[\pi+2\arctan(y^*/C)]/[C^2+(y(s)-y^*)^2]
$$

but i don't understand how to reach this solution.

Comment: Is it actually $\frac{ds}{dy}$ you want to find?  Since y is defined as a function of s, $\frac{dy}{ds}$ is more direct.  But $\frac{ds}{dy}= \frac{1}{\frac{dy}{ds}}$ so start by finding $\frac{dy}{ds}$ anyway.

Comment: Also, the first equation, $s= -cos(j\pi/n)$ is irrelevant since y is defined as a function of s.

Comment: Yeah they are calculating $\frac{ds}{dy(s)}$ in the paper. When i am calculating $\frac{dy}{ds}$ for $\frac{1}{\frac{dy}{ds}}$, i don't get the same result.

Comment: The last line is ambiguous due to the multiple division symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since y* and C are constants so is $\frac{1}{2}arctan(y*/C)$ so just call that C'.
You want to differentiate $y= \tan\left(\frac{\pi(s+1)}{4}+ C'\frac{s-1}{2}\right)+ y*$.

The derivative of $tan(y(x))$ with respect to x is $sec^2(y(x))\frac{dy}{dx}$ so the derivative of $\tan\left(\frac{\pi(s+1)}{4}+ C'\frac{s-1}{2}\right)$ with respect to s is $\sec^2\left(\frac{\pi(s+1)}{4}+ C'\frac{s-1}{2}\right)$  times $\frac{\pi}{4}+ C'\frac{1}{2}$.

That is, $\frac{dy}{ds}= \left(\frac{\pi}{4}+ \frac{1}{4}arctan(y*/C)\frac{s-1}{2}\right)\sec^2\left(\frac{\pi(s+1)}{4}+ C'\frac{s-1}{2}\right)$.

To get $\frac{ds}{dy}$ take the reciprocal of that.

Comment: You are totally right. I thought the result was not the same as in the paper, but it is just written different.